# finding a min-cut of graph with boost library

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, graph

Im trying to understand how to build a graph and run the `stoer_wagner_min_cut` algorithm with boost library.

so far, I built the graph with the `adjacency_matrix` container.

the problem is the making the`stoer_wagner_min_cut` work. I red [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/stoer_wagner_min_cut.html)
documentation and I encountered two things:

1. "The graph type must be a model of Vertex List Graph and Incidence Graph."
2. `WeightMap weights` as an input.

what does the first section means? is `adjacency_matrix` some type of "Vertex List Graph and Incidence Graph"? is there an example for that?

also, all the edges in the graph have weight of 1. I didn't understand how to assemble that `WeightMap weights`. and couldn't find any example for that.

**EDIT:**

this is what I could managed-

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/stoer_wagner_min_cut.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.h>

using namespace boost;
typedef adjacency_matrix<undirectedS> UGraph;


void main()
{
  static_property_map<UGraph, int>;   // im not sure about UGraph

  G = buildGraph();    // this function works fine

  parity_map = stoer_wagner_min_cut(G, ..?..);
}
```

how should I define this static property map to return int value of 1? im bit struggling with that.
also I saw that the return value of `stoer_wagner_min_cut` is `parity_map` (ParityMap must be a model of a Writable Property Map and its value type should be a bool type)

Im bit struggling with the building and using those maps, I will be happy for some guidance and example for that..

thanks.

Comment: Please ask 1 question at  a time. If you want _specific_ guidance, you need to include _specific_ code.

Comment: The parity map is _not_ the return value. it's an optional OUT parameter

Answer (score 4):

1. > what does the first section means? is adjacency_matrix some type of "Vertex List Graph and Incidence Graph"? is there an example for that?

   It means the graph type must *model* the named *concepts*. The concepts are documented here:

   - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_concepts.html

   ---
2. The second question is about property maps. They're also a [concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html)

   And in this case it would be easiest to supply a static property map:

   - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/property_map/doc/static_property_map.html

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c99380fd04bec19)</kbd>**

   ```
   #include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
   #include <boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp>
   #include <boost/graph/stoer_wagner_min_cut.hpp>
   #include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>

   using namespace boost;

   typedef adjacency_matrix<undirectedS> UGraph;

   UGraph buildGraph() {
       UGraph g(10);

       // todo

       return g;
   }

   #include <iostream>

   int main() {
       UGraph g = buildGraph(); // this function works fine

       int i = stoer_wagner_min_cut(g, boost::make_static_property_map<UGraph::edge_descriptor>(1));

       std::cout << "i: " << i << "\n";
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I understand what you wrote but still couldn't write code for that. I added some code, maybe now its more specific.. thanks.